# Does pandas read_excel actually open excel?

Tags: python, excel, matlab, pandas

This is just a question out of interest more than anything else. I come from a MATLAB background whereby to read in Excel files the function in MATLAB actually goes about opening Excel to read in the data. Obviously this takes alot of time and so it can be slow but the read_excel function with pandas does it much much faster. How does it go about reading in the file?

Comment: Your statement about Matlab is not complete. You can choose the `basic` mode when using `xlsread` which does not open excel.

Comment: Reading the file in what? Excel? Pandas? MATLAB? Python? Your microwave?

Comment: Pandas is open source: [`excel.py`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/excel.py) and so is its excel parser [`xlrd`](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd)

Comment: Even with basic mode on it is much much faster. And I thought it went without saying that it is reading excel files into pandas and MATLAB, bit of basic extrapolation would've told you that